# Does Ricci form has a globally smooth potential? (On a Kahler manifold)

Tags: differential-geometry, several-complex-variables, kahler-manifolds

Let $\left(M,\omega\right)$ be a Kahler manifold. We know that the
Ricci form $Ric\left(\omega\right)$ is locally by 
$$
Ric\left(\omega\right)=dd^{c}\log\left(\det g_{j\overline{k}}\right).
$$
Is it true that there is a smooth function $h\in C^{\infty}\left(M\right)$
such that $Ric\left(\omega\right)=dd^{c}h?$ That is, $Ric\left(\omega\right)$
has a globally smooth potential $h.$

Answer (score 4):

For the compact case, the existence of global function $h$ implies that 
$$[Ric(\omega)] = [d(d^c h)] =0$$
in $H^2(M, \mathbb R)$. But this class is the first Chern class $c_1(M)$ of $M$, so the global function $h$ does not exists whenever $c_1(M)\neq 0$.

On the other hand, if $c_1(M) = 0$, then $Ric(\omega) = d\alpha$ for some one form $\alpha$. Since $Ric(\omega)$ is a $1, 1$-form and is $d$-exact, the $\partial \bar\partial$-lemma implies that $Ric(\omega)$ is $\partial\bar\partial$-exact. Thus there is a function $h$ so that

$$Ric(\omega) = \frac{i}{2\pi} \partial \bar\partial h = d d^c h.$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer is so clear. However, can you explain why does the globally smooth potential $h$ always exist for the difference of two Ricci forms: $$Ric\left(\omega_{1}\right)-Ric\left(\omega_{2}\right)=dd^{c}h ?$$ 
(For any manifold)

Comment: Note that $\frac{\det  g_1}{\det g_2}$ is a global function and $ Ric(\omega_1)- Ric(w_2) = dd^c h $ for $h = log\frac{\det  g_1}{\det g_2}$. @Binjiu

Comment: It is not quite clear why $\frac{\det g_{1}}{\det g_{2}}$ is a global function since for example
$g_{1}$ should be $\left(g_{1}\left(\partial_{j},\partial_{\overline{k}}\right)\right)_{j\overline{k}},$
i.e, its formula itself is built on local coordinates. I guess that what
you mean is: even though $\frac{\det g_{1}}{\det g_{2}}$ is defined
by using local coordinates, it does not depend on the choice of local
coordinates since the quotient cancels out the determinant of the
coordinates change.

Comment: That's what I mean, @Binjiu.